# How do I Use a Function as a Parameter?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like a function that will unprotect and reprotect my Worksheet.

The function I have currently is as follows:

```
Public Function RunProtect(fun As Function, sheet As Worksheet)
    Dim protected As Boolean: protected = False
    If sheet.ProtectContents = True Then
        protected = True
        sheet.Unprotect
    End If

    'Code to run fun 

    If protected = True Then
        sheet.protect
    End If
End Function
```

Is this possible or is there an easier way? I have to unprotect my sheets when trying to edit my tables in using VBA.

Comment: Protect once with `UserInterfaceOnly:=true`, and you won't need to unprotect each time.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you sir.

Comment: You would have to write your function in a class module. Then it would have properties (maybe methods) just like e.g. the worksheet. Let's say you named your class Funky, then you would put in this function 'fun as Funky'. But for someone to do this you have to show the code of the function.

Comment: @GSerg You have no idea how my mind is blown right now, I had the same problem for a month at least, thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

Protect once with `UserInterfaceOnly:=true`, and you won't need to unprotect each time. -GSerg

Thank you!

Comment: Although you provided an answer to your own question, you can still "Accept" it - this lets others know that you are no longer in need of active assistance. However, this doesn't close the question and still allows others to post answers for future readability.