# Is it possible to disable the 'Auto Increment' feature in excel cells?

Tags: excel, vba

My question relates to an Excel feature where it incrementally increases the value of a cell, for example:

```
--------
   1
-------- <-- if I insert a row here
   1
--------
```

then Excel 'auto adds' to the value in the cell below...like so

```
--------
   1
-------- 
   1       <-- new row inserted
--------
   2       <-- original value increased from 1 to 2
--------
```

Is it possible to turn this feature Off? preferably through VBA as I'm inserting the rows with a Form Button and Macro.

Thanks.

EDIT 1: I have tried formatting the cells to Text to no avail.

EDIT 2: How I am inserting the new Rows

```
Dim row As Long
Dim varResponse As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Message box confirming user is doing the right thing
varResponse = MsgBox("Add another row? 'Yes' or 'No'", vbYesNo, "Add Row")
If varResponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

'Carry on with adding a row.....

'Unprotect sheet
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="****"

'Insert new row on button row
row = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.row
Rows(row + 1).Insert

'AutoFill from 1 row above new row, for 1 row down
Rows(row).AutoFill Destination:=Rows(row + 1 & ":" & row), Type:=xlFillDefault

'Clear cells D-J on new row
Range("D" & row & ":J" & row).ClearContents

'Protect sheet again
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="***"
```

Comment: Please show how you are inserting rows.

Comment: @GSerg added how I am adding new rows

Comment: Well, you are using `Autofill`, and that is what `Autofill` is supposed to do. Alternatively, replacing `xlFillDefault` with `xlFillCopy` may also do what you want, depending on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you [don't need to unprotect each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453611/vba-excel-how-do-i-use-a-function-as-a-parameter#comment93779918_53453611).

Comment: Ok, I used autofill (not least because I am inexperienced ;) )  but also because the rows I am inserting do have some data/formulas in certain cells that I want to be retained. The row extends from A-S and it is the cells D through J where I clear the contents and don't wish for the AutoFill feature to be present. Thanks educating me on not needing to unprotect each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing xlFillDefault with xlFillCopy may also do what you want, depending on what you actually want to do. – GSerg