# Lock specific rows and columns in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code which performs a particular functionality.
Now, I want to unlock the sheet before I run this piece of code and after this code is done executing, I want to lock the row 1 and columns A, B, I, Q using a password.

```vb
For i = 2 To LastRowAT
    If sht.Range("B" & i).Value = "BK" And sht.Range("D" & i).Value = "Allocated" And sht.Range("C" & i).Value = Max_date Then
        If sht.Range("A" & i).Value = Workbooks("Co_insurer Sample File.xlsx").Worksheets("QUIDAM-INSURERS").Range("A" & i).Value Then
            Workbooks("Co_insurer Sample File.xlsx").Worksheets("QUIDAM-INSURERS").Range("A" & i & ":V" & i).Copy _
                Workbooks("Smart_Excel_BK.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("Q" & (LastRowBK))
            wsDest.Range("A" & LastRowBK).Value = "BK"
            wsDest.Range("B" & LastRowBK).Value = Max_date
            LastRowBK = LastRowBK + 1
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453611/vba-excel-how-do-i-use-a-function-as-a-parameter#comment93779918_53453611

Comment: How can I protect only specific rows and columns using VBA?