# How to break links to values in VBA on a protected worksheet? Run-time error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to break the links to values while copying over multiple worksheets from one workbook to another in VBA.

I am presented with Run-time error '1004': the sheets are protected, however I am unable to unprotect these sheets.

The problem hits at the `.Value = .Value` part of the function where it runs the error. Is there another method I can use?

I have tried to `wb.BreakLink` link function however this was unsuccessful.

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For Each smallrng In Range("G16:Q16,G40:Q69").Areas
        With smallrng
            .Value = .Value
```

I expect the output to remove all formulas and present only values within the specified range once copied over.

Comment: `I am unable to unprotect` - are you able to protect the original sheet in [user mode only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453611/vba-excel-how-do-i-use-a-function-as-a-parameter#comment93779918_53453611) to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the worksheet is also copying the protection mode. So, if you can create the sheet *without* copying it, then you should be able to transfer values to the new worksheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
Dim newWS As Worksheet
Dim protectedWS As Worksheet
Dim smallRng As Range

Set protectedWS = Worksheets(1)
Set newWS = Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

protectedWS.Cells.Copy

With newWS
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    For Each smallRng In protectedWS.Range("G16:Q16,G40:Q69").Areas
        .Range(smallRng.Address).Value = smallRng.Value
    Next
End With
End Sub
```