# Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) not working always

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in VBA and I have an issue with a Private Sub Worksheet_Change code - it is not always working.
I want when a cell in column A changes it's value to write on the same row in column B the Windows user who made the change.

Please see below my code, written in Sheet1, not in a Module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:=Password

    x = Target.Row         

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A" & x)) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B" & x).Value = Environ("USERNAME")
    End If

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=Password

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=Password` will make the sheet non-writable. Is that the problem?

Comment: `Target` is not necessarily a single cell. You [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453611/how-do-i-use-a-function-as-a-parameter#comment93779918_53453611) need to unprotect each time either.

Comment: Please, how can I change it? I am a beginner in VBA. :)

Comment: Can you explain _it is not always working_ a bit further please.  Does it throw an error?

Comment: For example: if I modify the value from one cell, it works - in column B in the same row write Windows user name. If I modify 3 cells (copy from another worksheet), it doesn't write Windows user name in 3 corresponding lines in column B.

Comment: That 100% sounds like what @Gserg said.... `Target` isn't a single cell in that case, it's three cells.  You'll need to loop through each cell referenced in `Target`.

Answer (score 1):

1. first insure the cells in column **A** are un-locked. *(coder)*
2. Create a password String variable. *(code)*
3. Allow more than one cell to be changed *(code)*
4. Prevent Event re-entry *(code)*

The first step should be done by the coder.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim x As Long, pswrd As String, cell As Range, inter As Range

    pswrd = "secret"
    Set inter = Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target)
    If inter Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:=pswrd
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In inter
            x = cell.Row
            Range("B" & x).Value = Environ("USERNAME")
        Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=pswrd

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Based on  Darren Bartrup-Cook's suggestion, we can drop the *loop*:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim x As Long, pswrd As String, cell As Range, inter As Range

    pswrd = "secret"
    Set inter = Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target)
    If inter Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:=pswrd
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            inter.Offset(0, 1).Value = Environ("USERNAME")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=pswrd

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm thinking `Target.Offset(, 1) = Environ("USERNAME")` would work instead of looping through each cell?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  **GREAT IDEA** .................I will test!

Comment: It is faster than the initial code. Thanks all!

Comment: Good stuff.  I'd best delete my earlier comment where I said _"You'll need to loop through each cell referenced in Target."_ now. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  Your Comment is **extremely valuable** to me, I never thought of it before.