# VBA Protected sheet prevents macro from replacing text but cells are not protected

Tags: excel, vba, replace

So I have this macro:

```
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fetch").Range("C33"))

Range("C33").Value = text
Range("B3").Value = text

Cells.Replace What:="ÿþ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

The excel sheet is protected, but the two cells C33 and B3 are not since i want text to be replaced in those two cells.

When i run the above macro with the sheet unprotected, it works flawlessly.
It runs together with a script that import a string of text to Excel.

When i protect the sheet, the macro does not replace the text but leave it unchanged.

Basically i just want the macro to run, target the text in those two cells, replace the specified part with nothing, and leave the rest, even when the sheet is protected.

Comment: You need to remove the protection (ws.Unprotect) , update the fields and re-protect (ws.Protect)

Comment: 1. Do you understand what **your above code does**, especially `Replace` part? It tries to replace "ÿþ\" string from **all active sheet cells**. Do the two cells in discussion have that string like value? 2. What do you mean by "cells are not protected", since protection prevents their text replacement?

Comment: @ceci [Bad advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453611/how-do-i-use-a-function-as-a-parameter#comment93779918_53453611).

Comment: @GSerg you can manually flag cells to be unprotected separately when you protect sheets. When you then protect the whole sheet, those specific cells become exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- Cells C33 and B3 are on 'Fetch' and are **not locked**, and
- The sheet 'Fetch' is protected

The following would work:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fetch")

    Union(.Range("C33"), .Range("B3")).Replace What:="ÿþ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
            :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            
End With
```

There is no need to remove the sheet protection if those two cells are unlocked.

---

Alternatively, you could perform the replacement one cell at a time using:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fetch")

    .Range("C33").Value = Replace(.Range("C33").Value, "ÿþ", "")
    .Range("B3").Value = Replace(.Range("B3").Value, "ÿþ", "")
            
End With
```

---

Finally, now we have a clearer understanding of what is going on and how the text gets there in the first place, the following would probably be the simplest method:

```
Sub ParentPath_Import_To_Excel()

    Dim myFile As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim textline As String

    myFile = "H:\Temp\PublicFolder-powershell\ParentPath-FETCH\fullpath_X.txt"
      
    Open myFile For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, textline
            text = text & textline
        Loop
    Close #1

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fetch")
        .Range("C33").Value = Replace(text, "ÿþ", "")
        .Range("B3").Value = .Range("C33").Value
        .Range("B3").Activate
    End With
        
End Sub
```

If the above fails and errors when writing to the cells, then you have not unlocked the two cells that you're trying to write to. You can either unlock the cells once, within the formatting menu (being the best solution) or you could unlock the entire sheet and relock it during runtime - but that is very much a sledgehammer to crack a nut kind of solution.

Answer (score -2):

I decided to go with the unprotect method, since the union suggestion above, did not work when the sheet was protected.

So i ended up with the following:

```
Sub ParentPath_Import_To_Excel()

    Dim myFile As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim textline As String

myFile = "H:\Temp\PublicFolder-powershell\ParentPath-FETCH\fullpath_X.txt"

Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fetch").Range("C33"))

Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
     text = text & textline
Loop

Close #1

Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fetch").Range("C33"))

Range("C33").Value = text 'writes text to cell C33
Range("B3").Value = text 'writes text to cell B3

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fetch").Unprotect  ' This removes the protection of the worksheet, so the search for the BOM-chars can be done, and changed.

Cells.Replace What:="ÿþ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fetch").Protect ' This protects the worksheet again

End Sub
```

Comment: You have not solved you problem, you have hidden it behind the curtain. This code does not do what you think it does, and the error you are getting with protected cells is an indication of that.

Comment: The code in my answer is tested and worked fine on a protected sheet. I would perhaps try it again, making sure both of those cells have the locked flag unset.

Comment: GSerg - for this spesific case, it is just easier to unlock the sheet, do what i need and then lock it again. And your solution with UNION did not work, the result did remove ÿþ when the sheet was protected and the cells not locked. 

CLR, it is a text string and is insignificant, i changed the original post to reflect. I just removed the backslash from the original text file , the ÿþ is still present as it is "BOM" characters that are invisible. When you import the string of text into Excel with VBA it becomes visible as clear text since the original txt file was Unicode.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the first lines of my answer? *"Assuming that: Cells C33 and B3 are on 'Fetch' and are **not locked**."* If they're not locked, then you can write to / amend them - regardless of the protection status of the sheet. If they are locked, then of course, you'll need to unprotect the whole sheet. If my assumption is incorrect, then let me know and I can give you an alternative solution. Of course, telling us the error you receive and where the code breaks would help.

Comment: No i did not miss it. They are not locked, and yet your script failed with the same error...in other words, not removing the text from the cells i want to remove from on the otherwise protected sheet.

Comment: That said, the 2nd, suggestion you gave to try where you do it for each cell **does** work.  So thanks for that. :)